# Create table with unknown number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable, pivot

I have the following table:

| Team | Product | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | P1 | 1 |
| T2 | P1 | 2 |
| T3 | P1 | 3 |
| T1 | P2 | 4 |
| T2 | P2 | 5 |
| T3 | P2 | 6 |
| T1 | P3 | 7 |
| T2 | P3 | 8 |
| T3 | P3 | 9 |

With this query:

```
SELECT Team AS Team, P1, P2, P3
FROM team_data AS td
PIVOT (
 sum(Number)
 FOR Product
 IN (P1, P2, P3)
) AS td;
```

I´m able to put it into this format:

| Team | P1 | P2 | P3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| T2 | 2 | 5 | 8 |
| T3 | 3 | 6 | 9 |

My goal is now to make this dynamic. I want this to work with an unknown number of products. The number of teams should already be variable.

Comment: *With this query:* This SQL code is wrong in MySQL. Maybe you use SQL Server (MS SQL)?

Comment: You are right. I edited the sum(Count) to sum(Number). It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to work quite well in this case:

```
Declare @PivotCols Varchar(2000)   
Set @PivotCols=''
Select @PivotCols=(Select Distinct '['+ product +'],' from team_data2 for Xml Path(''))
Set @PivotCols=SUBSTRING(@PivotCols,1,len(@PivotCols)-1)
--Dynemic Query To Run Pivot   
exec('Select * From team_data2 as tmp pivot (sum(Number) for  product in ('+@PivotCols+')) as tbl')
```

In this case the testdata was called "team_data2".